# How to find the period of a simple pendulum in an elevator going up with an acceleration?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, harmonic-oscillator, free-body-diagram

How to find the period of a simple pendulum in an elevator going up with an acceleration of $a$.

Don't just say, $T=2 \pi$ $\sqrt{ \frac l {g+a}}$

I want to know how the above equation is formed.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I downvoted this because the answer is on this site and one 10 second search found it.

Comment: I searched you know but couldn't find anything helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Einstein's Equivalence Principle (also derivable I believe from Newton's laws) states that being in an accelerating frame of reference is indistinguishable from being under a gravitational force.

In particular, the mechanical laws in an accelerating frame of reference are the same as if a gravitational field of equivalent magnitude were added in the opposite direction to that of the acceleration.

So in your frame of reference accelerating upward at a in a standard gravitational field of g downward, we see that this is equivalent to a gravitational field of (g+a) downward.

So we can take any equation involving the local gravitational field g which applies in an inertial frame, and change g to (g+a), and this new version will apply in your accelerating frame.

Comment: Can you please, help me in deriving this using Newton's laws?